# Jquery drop down option on based previous selction

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Is it possible to get data from the database based on the previous drop down selection?

For example:

```
<select id="paramscountries" class="chzn-done" style="display: none;" name="params[countries][]" multiple="true" size="10">
    <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="2">Albania</option>
    <option value="3">Algeria</option>
    <option value="4">USA</option>
</select>
```

If I select USA from the above list it will make a query & get all the states name from  the database. For example from states.php & will show all the states name in another drop down selection without reloading that page.

Comment: `Is it possible to get data from the database based on the previous drop down selection?` Answer = `Yes`

Comment: Thanks but how I can do such list ?

Comment: Too many ways to describe here, I suggest you learn about AJAX, which can communicate without reloading the page with your backend(PHP/MySQL) and then jQuery/Javascript for handling the returned values and making/populating the 2nd stage drop-down.

Comment: I did the query with php & it's sending data in JSON format like this: {"222":[{"virtuemart_state_id":"65","virtuemart_vendor_id":"1","virtuemart_country_id":"222","virtuemart_worldzone_id":"0","state_name":"England"},{"virtuemart_state_id":"66","virtuemart_vendor_id":"1","virtuemart_country_id":"222","virtuemart_worldzone_id":"0","state_name":"Northern Ireland"}]} But I want to retrieve virtuemart_state_id & state_name to make 2nd drop down list.

Comment: Have a look at how to iterate over the JSON and use it as you like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594241/how-to-convert-json-to-array-and-loop-over-it-in-jquery/24594411#24594411 then have a look and learn how to add elements in jQuery

Comment: But what if it's from an external URL like: http://example.com/state.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56834/discussion-between-jibon57-and-rob-schmuecker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use Javascript or jQuery for this and use it to post to a page that will return your results.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="paramscountries" class="chzn-done" style="display: block;" onchange="getNewList($(this).val());" name="params[countries][]" multiple="true" size="10">
    <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="2">Albania</option>
    <option value="3">Algeria</option>
    <option value="4">USA</option>
</select>

<select name="states" id="states">
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getNewList(country) {
    $.post('post.api.php', {'api': 'getStates', 'countries': country}, function(response) {
        var obj = $.pareseJSON(response);
        $('#states').html(obj.states);
    });
}
```

post.api.php page

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['api'])){

    if($_POST['api'] == 'getStates'){

        // sdet the countries array to a variable
        $countries = $_POST['countries'];

        // set a variable to hold the results
        $results = array();

        // query your db
        $stm = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `your_database` WHERE `country` IN("'.implode('","', $countries).'")');
        $stm->execute();
        if($stm->rowCount() > 0){
            foreach($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
                $results['states'] .= '<option value="'.$row['stateName'].'">'.$row['stateName'].'</option>';
            }
        }            
        echo json_encode($results);
    }

}
```

I would do something like that. Hopefully there is enough here to get you rolling.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have php file already & sending JSON already like this: {"222":[{"virtuemart_state_id":"65","virtuemart_vendor_id":"1","virtuemart_country_id":"222","virtuemart_worldzone_id":"0","state_name":"England"},{"virtuemart_state_id":"66","virtuemart_vendor_id":"1","virtuemart_country_id":"222","virtuemart_worldzone_id":"0","state_name":"Northern Ireland"}]} & I want to make drop down with virtuemart_state_id & state_name .

Comment: You can convert the json to an object with jQuery. use var obj = $.parseJSON(response); as shown in my example above. then you can iterate through the object and access the 2 fields you need $.each(obj, function(i,v){ console.log(v.virtuemart_state_id); });

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery ajax request. something like this

**jQuery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#paramscountries').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'states.php'
            ,data:{val: $(this).val()}
            ,dataType:'json'
            ,type: 'POST'
            ,success:function(data){
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    var dropDownValue = '<option value="'+ data[i] +'">'+ data[i] +'</option>'
                    $('#secondDropDownList').append(dropDownValue);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**In states.php**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db_Name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if(isset($POST['val'])){
$var = $_POST['val'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_column_name = '$var'");
$arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $arr[] =  $row['name'];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

**In HTML**

```
<select id="secondDropDownList"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks. But how I can retrieve virtuemart_state_id & state_name if the format is like this: {"222":[{"virtuemart_state_id":"65","virtuemart_vendor_id":"1","virtuemart_country_id":"222","virtuemart_worldzone_id":"0","state_name":"England"},{"virtuemart_state_id":"66","virtuemart_vendor_id":"1","virtuemart_country_id":"222","virtuemart_worldzone_id":"0","state_name":"Northern Ireland"}]}